# How to clear PostgreSQL psql command history

Tags: command-line, psql

When login to the database using `psql -u postgres`, all the commands entered there can be seen in and recalled from history.

I created a role with a password and I would like to clear that entry.

How can I clear the history?

Comment: With PostgreSQL 14.5 it's "psql -U postgres" with "U" capitalized.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Please check on the `/home/user/.psql_history`, then open the file if we want we can clear all the commands or the necessary commands and save the file.

Comment: I found it under currently logged in user.

Answer (score 6):

If you used `sudo -u postgres`, the file should be in the home of your `postgres` user. In my case it is `/var/lib/postgresql/.psql_history`.

Edit: I misread your original command and thought sudo was used.

Comment: For Postgres13 on Centos 9, the file was `/var/lib/pgsql/.psql_history`.